# How to register udf with input Array[(Date, Double)] in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to write a udf whose parameter is Array[(Date, Double)]( the result of collect_list(struct(col1, col2)).

```
function (c) {
return function () {
var baseDF = c.cu.loadParquetDF(c.sqc, '/path', true).selectExpr('`date`', '`value`', '`svalue`');
var resDF = new (Java.type('org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer'))().setStatement('select date_range_build(valuePairs) from (select collect_list(struct(`date`,`value`)) as valuePairs from __THIS__)').transform(baseDF);
return resDF;
}().limit(200);
}
```

(1) When I use the following definition:

```
def DateRangeBuild(dateValuePairs: Seq[(AnyRef, Number)]) = {...}
sql.udf.register("date_range_build", TimeRangeUdfs.DateRangeBuild(_: Seq[(AnyRef, Number)]))
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2

(2) When I use the following definition:

```
def DateRangeBuild(dateValuePairs: GenericRowWithSchema) = {...}
sql.udf.register("date_range_build", TimeRangeUdfs.DateRangeBuild(_: GenericRowWithSchema))
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

(3) When I use the following definition:

```
def DateRangeBuild(dateValuePairs: Seq[GenericRowWithSchema]) = {...}
sql.udf.register("date_range_build", TimeRangeUdfs.DateRangeBuild(_: Seq[GenericRowWithSchema]))
```

IDEA hint: No implicit arguments of type: Nothing, Nothing.

After assembly and run:

Undefined function: 'date_range_build'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input should be `Seq[Row]`, then map the `Row` to `(Date,Double)` using `getAs[T](...)` methods on `Row`

Comment: GenericRowWithSchema extends GenericRow, GenericRow extends Row.
Even if I use Seq[Row] as the input, I still can't register it with the function sql.udf.register successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
 I remember I tried replacing Seq[GenericRowWithSchema] with Seq[Row] yesterday, but  the IDEA hinted again when I registered it as udf, so I stopped.
Right now, I tried again, even though it hinted, I still assembled and ran, it worked.